# java equals. method error when debug

Tags: java

```
public  boolean end(Cat cat, Mouse mouse){
    String d="drowned";
    String e="escaped";

    String s=mouse.checkMoblity();
    System.out.println(s);

// error next line
    if(s.equals(d)){
        return true;
    }

    else if(s.equals(e)){
        return true;
    }

    else if(mouse.getLocation()==cat.getLocation()){
        return true;
    }

    else return false;
}
```

This is part of my code.  When I tried to debug it, it gave me an error on the equals method. I don't know how to fix it.

When I compile..

> ```
> nullException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at Chase.end(Chase.java:93)
> at Chase.playGame(Chase.java:23)
> at Chase.main(Chase.java:115)
> ```

Comment: Please include the error message in your question and create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately "it gave me a error"  isn't nearly enough information... was the error at compile-time or execution time? What was the error? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I cannot run the program. And when i debug it, the erorr points to the line that I marked

Comment: Most porbably, the call to `mouse.checkMobility()` returns `null` and therefore `s.equals(...)` results in a `NullPointerException`. This, it is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: Isn't this a followup of your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361226/java-match-point)? The one you asked an hour ago? You shouldn't post multiple questions regarding the same problem. (For others: the issue in the other question was that `checkMobility` was returning `null`, so @Turing85 you are completely right.)

Comment: Yes. that is it.  mouse.checkMobility() did always return null. I don't know why and I am fixing it.

Comment: Oh i am sorry.  Becasue I just think they are different types of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mouse.checkMoblity() returns null.